# Hide folder from directory listing in Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

This seems like a simple thing, but I've been unable to find an answer

I'm using Azure Storage, and I have a folder in the container that has some sensitive documents in it. So I'd like to be able to "hide" the folder and it's contents from the directory listing. Is this possible? The only thing I can find is to change the Access Level of the entire container.

If there's not a way to do this, what's the proper way to hide Azure Storage docs from public access?

Comment: Why not store those documents in a separate container?  Also, with ADLS Gen2 , you can set access at the folder level.  You'd need to create a storage account of that type and migrate to it I guess as it's too late to do it now IF your container is not of said type.

Comment: Afaik there is no way to hide it. Best way is to control access with RBAC.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature in **Azure Storage** to hide the content in the **Azure Container** folder.

There is an alternate approach to secure the **Azure Storage container** files.

Thanks to **Niclas** for suggesting the same.

Assign **RBAC** roles to your **Azure Container**, like below.

**Azure Portal > Storage accounts > Select your storage account > Container > Select your container > Access Control (IAM)**

[image]

When I tried with another **Azure AD** user, who doesn't have any RBAC roles to check the **Azure container** files.

The user is unable to access the **Azure Container**.

[image]

I have assigned **Storage Blob Data Contributor** to the same user on **Storage Account** to check the **Azure Container** files.

[image]

Once assign the **RBAC** roles to the user, the same user can access the **Azure Container**.

[image]

Referance:  [Assign an Azure role for access to blob data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal).